# "I am wondering" or "I wonder"?

Tags: word-usage

How to express my surprise at the moment?

> I am wondering how easy the task is!

or

> I wonder how easy the task is!

Comment: The second is close to "How easy is the task?" while the first is close to "I am spending a little time thinking about the question"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be confusing the verb `to wonder` with the phrase `to wonder at`.

Generally, when English speakers use `to wonder`, they mean [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wonder#dictionary-entry-2):

> to feel curiosity or doubt

When they use `to wonder at`, they mean [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wonder#dictionary-entry-2):

> to be in a state of [astonishment or admiration]

Given your definition, your options are:

> I am wondering at how easy the task is!

or

> I wonder at how easy the task is!

"I wonder" is known as the Present Simple tense. Generally, this is used for permanent states.

"I am wondering" is known as the Present Continuous tense. Generally, this is used for changes, trends, and transient states.

Thus, I would suggest that

> I am wondering at how easy this task is!

is probably your best bet.

Comment: But I’d probably just say, “I’m surprised/amazed at how easy this task is!”  “I wonder at” in this context just sounds out of place.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the answer in the comment. It's better to use another word instead.

I'd say:

> I’m surprised this task is so easy!